Find largest ellipsoid of given axes contained in a box
I want to find the biggest ellipsoid of fixed axes contained within a given box. More precisely, assume I want to maximize the Mahalanobis distance $(x-\mu)^T \Sigma^{-1} (x-\mu)$ where $\mu$ and $\Sigma$ are known under the box constraints
$$\mu_i-3\Sigma_{ii} \leq x_i \leq \mu_i+3\Sigma_{ii} \qquad \forall i.$$
Since $\Sigma$ is a covariance matrix and its inverse the precision matrix, the objective function is convex, feasible set is convex and we have a maximization problem hence it is a concave optimization problem.
Intuitively, the maximum distance will be achieved when (at least) one inequality constraint is active (which, if I am not mistaken, implies, by symmetry that the two "sandwich" constraints will in fact be active). A naive idea would be to select one variable at the time, check if the other constraints are feasible and compute the objective. And keep the best at the end. Is it correct, and foremost, is there a better approach ?
How to solve the more general problem where the constraints are
$a_i\leq x_i \leq b_i$ ?

I believe this can be formulated and solved as a CONVEX optimization problem, per section 8.4.2 of  Boyd & Vandenberghe "Convex Optimization" https://web.stanford.edu/~boyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf . A CVX implementation is shown at  https://web.cvxr.com/cvx/examples/cvxbook/Ch08_geometric_probs/html/max_vol_ellip_in_polyhedra.html
